# How to know a running progress's using configuration file?

Tags: linux, debian

In my linux OS, there running the `httpd`:

```
root      4686     1  0 09:56 ?        00:00:00 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP
daemon    4689  4686  0 09:56 ?        00:00:00 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP
daemon    4690  4686  0 09:56 ?        00:00:00 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP
daemon    4691  4686  0 09:56 ?        00:00:00 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP
daemon    4692  4686  0 09:56 ?        00:00:00 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP
daemon    4693  4686  0 09:56 ?        00:00:00 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP
daemon    4694  4686  0 09:56 ?        00:00:00 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP
daemon    4713  4686  0 09:56 ?        00:00:00 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL -DPHP
```

But how can I know the running `/opt/lampp/bin/httpd`'s configuration file?

---

The OS version is `Debian GNU/Linux 9 \n \l`.

Comment: How did you find it out eventually?

Answer (score 0):

Try command lsof and grep the specific daemons you want to see what files are these daemons are using.

Comment: can you give an example?